# VLC - libvdpau error with intel graphics

Tags: arch-linux, vlc, rtmp, vaapi, vdpau

I am using archlinux trying to connect to an RTSP stream on my local network (local IP camera) and am getting very hit-and-miss performance from VLC. Most of the time the connection runs just fine, but sometimes the connection *freezes* and I have to close and reopen to resume. Running from the terminal shows the following:

```
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
[0000000000bbf1f8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007fa54800c618] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
...
...
[00007fa54800c618] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
```

This is obviously a bit off as this is an intel laptop with no nvidia components. I cannot figure out where/why it is looking for nvidia files (or if it is even relevant to the problem)

Running `grep -iE 'vdpau|dri driver' ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` yields:

```
[ 99171.065] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[ 99171.065] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
```

Running `vainfo` yields:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.3)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile - 1.7.3
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
  VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

I've read the relevant arch wiki articles (I believe), but cannot get a stable connection. I have `extra/libva`, `extra/libva-intel-driver`, and `extra/libva-vdpau-driver` installed and this seems like it should do it... what am I missing?

Comment: As stupid as I may sound, have you [selected](https://hacklog.mu/content/images/2015/11/opensuse-vlc.png) "VA-API" in Input & Codecs settings dialog?

Comment: I have it set to auto currently. I had tried the VDPAU and various VA-API options previously, but it's worth double checking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment.

After making sure your video drivers are up to date, try checking if any of the packages provide the file VLC is complaining about: `pacman -Qi libva libva-intel-driver libva-vdpau-driver | grep libvdpau_nvidia.so`. As Dmitry commented, make sure `VA-API` is selected as the hardware accelerated decoding setting, or try setting that to `Auto`.

Additionally, can you play the same stream with another player, such as `mplayer` or `mpv`?